# Register all the services at once using Default DI Container from ASP.NET 5 similar to Autofac

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-mvc

With ASP.NET 5, there's already a DI shipped as default and it looks interesting. I have been using Autofac with MVC 5 which has the option to register all the assembly at once. Here is a sample code that register all the classes that ends with "Service" in Autofac.

```
// Autofac Configuration for API
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());

...
...

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("IMS.Service"))
                      .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                      .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

My question is, is there any thing similar to this in Default DI container from asp.net 5 where you can register all the services at once ?

Answer (score 20):

> My question is, is there any thing similar to this in Default DI container from asp.net 5 where you can register all the services at once ?

Not OOTB, but Kristian Hellang created a cool package named [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) that adds assembly scanning capabilities to the built-in container. You can find it on [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor).

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<ITransientService>()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITransientService>())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithTransientLifetime()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IScopedService>())
            .As<IScopedService>()
            .WithScopedLifetime());
```

Comment: Does scrutor work with .net core 2.0? I can't get it to install with nuget.

Comment: @mac10688 Yes, it should. It targets netstandard1.0 and 1.6, which should both work on .NET Core 2.0. What are the issues you're seeing? Can you file an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit late to the party but I'm guessing there's no other way to do this without a NuGet package? Curious if this has been updated at all

Answer (score 3):

You can still use the `Autofac` with Asp.net(5/Core) or MVC 6. You need to change the signature of `ConfigureServices` method to return `IServiceProvider` and argument as `IServiceCollection`.

E.g.

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     // We add MVC here instead of in ConfigureServices.
     services.AddMvc();

     // Create the Autofac container builder.
     var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

     // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
     builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());

     // Populate the services.
     builder.Populate(services);

     // Build the container.
     var container = builder.Build();

     // Resolve and return the service provider.
     return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
 }
```

See more details [here](http://alexmg.com/autofac-4-0-alpha-1-for-asp-net-5-0-beta-3/) about integrating Autofac with Asp.net(5/Core).

Answer (score 3):

It might surprise you that most of what you need can be done in few lines without reliance on third-party packages!.. Once someone else has figured out what those few lines should be

For example, here is a [handful of concise DI extensions](https://github.com/ravendb/samples-yabt/blob/master/back-end/Domain/Infrastructure/ModuleRegistrationExtensions.cs) from [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac) and [NetCore.AutoRegisterDi](https://github.com/JonPSmith/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi) (all methods are annotated with source links). It lets you write registration logic like ([example](https://github.com/ravendb/samples-yabt/blob/master/back-end/Domain/Infrastructure/ConventionModule.cs)):

```
var types = typeof(BaseService<>).Assembly
                        .GetTypes()
                        .Where(t =>
                                !t.IsAbstract &&
                                t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(BaseService<>)))
                        ).ToList();
services.RegisterAsImplementedInterfaces(types, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

This blog post, [.NET Core project without Autofac](https://alex-klaus.com/webapi-proj-without-autofac/), has more examples and covers limitations if you want take one level further.

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines to **.net 6** program.cs file :

```
var appServices = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith("Service") && s.IsInterface == false).ToList();
foreach (var appService in appServices)
    builder.Services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(appService, appService, ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
```

I don't write interface for my services (for writing less code).

These codes find all Types with these conditions : be class and not interface and EndsWith : "Service".

Then add all service classes to the .net DI container.

https://github.com/mammadkoma/webapi/blob/master/WebApi/Program.cs

Then **inject** the service classes everywhere you want, for example in UserController **constructor** :
https://github.com/mammadkoma/webapi/blob/master/WebApi/Controllers/UserController/UserController.cs

Comment: Seems very useful when you have all the services defined on same project. I just have a different project. The optimal solution in my case will be loading the assembly first and finding all the services as in your example. Can you suggest a script for that as well?

Comment: It's better you have one project too , I always have one project.

Comment: Did some little tweak, modified as follows `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Assembly_Name").GetTypes().Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith("Service") && s.IsInterface == false).ToList()`
but still got the error, Some services are not able to be constructed