# How resolve (DI) Dependency injection object chain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am going to develop enterprise application and have many project in solution problem is suppose 
1-  Webapi                project 
2-  Services                 project 
3-  DataModel          project

Webapi project calls services project and Services project calls DataModel project problem is I have to add both(Services, DataModel) projects dll in Webapi project and add all classe and interface in Startup class like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{ 
  services.AddTransient<IDocConverterProAuth, DocConverterProAuthentication>(); 
  services.AddTransient<IFileConverter, FileConverter>(); 
  services.AddTransient<IFileConversionService, FileConversionService>(); 
}
```

But I have 50 project and hundreds class. I have to add all references in Webapi project. I thing it is not correct way because DataModel project is not used in Webapi project only Services project uses DataModel project so resolve dependency in Services project so kindly guide me how I possible my development environment is

1-  Visual studio enterprise 2017
2-  .net core 2.1
3-  C#

Comment: Autofac (DI container) allows you to separate registrations into modules. Perhaps somebody has built something around the .NET Core DI ServiceCollection to achieve a similar goal? Alternatively, you could change `ConfigureServices` to return an `IServiceProvider` and use a different DI container that implements this.

Comment: First of, read about composition root in DI. The application should be bootstrap as close to the application entry point as possible, in your case that is the web api project. Secondly, you can register all interfaces and instances via an assembly. look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35490207

Comment: The common pattern für the .NET Core DI is to use extensoin methods on `IServiceCollection` to do your registrations and call it like `services.AddXyz()`

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of scenario longtime back (like 2010), the solution I chose in that case was scanning the assembly to find all the contracts, giving contract implementation a unique name, for example:
     abc.business.interfaces.dll
and the corresponding implementation was in 
    abc.business.dll

Using such nomenclature, i was able to identify implementation assembly for corresponding interfaces and then register them in the container for DI.

So if you don't want to write every DI injection, you have to write such implementation. 
I think there are also some ready-made solution available, but I haven't used such solution so can't recommend.